# How to get error.data in RTK Query using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rtk-query

If I output `error` to the console, I get:

```
{
    status: 401,
    data: "Invalid password"
}
```

If I try to output `error.data` to the console, I get an error:

> The "data" property does not exist in the
> "FetchBaseQueryError|SerializedError" type. The "data" property does
> not exist in the "SerializedError" type.ts(2339)

Full code:

```
const [login, { data, error }] = useLoginMutation()

const handleSubmit: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    if (credential.user_email.trim() !== '' && credential.user_password.trim() !== '') {
        await login(credential)
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (data !== undefined) {
        localStorage.token = data.token
    }
}, [data])

useEffect(() => {
    if (error !== undefined) {
        console.log(error.data)
    }
}, [error])
```

Tell me pls how to do it correctly using typescript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Type Guard function - more is explained in [Type Safe Error Handling](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#type-safe-error-handling)

```js
 function isFetchBaseQueryError(
  error: unknown
): error is FetchBaseQueryError {
  return typeof error === 'object' && error != null && 'status' in error
}


useEffect(() => {
    if (isFetchBaseQueryError(error)) {
        console.log(error.data)
    }
}, [error])
```

Or if you don't need to do this a lot you can also just do

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (error && 'status' in error) {
        console.log(error.data)
    }
}, [error])
```